# What is it called when you are sent by the organization you work for to do a one day task in another city?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose that you work in a company located in London. One day they send you to install some equipment in Manchester. The whole task takes one day and you return to London at the same night. They will pay you extra money for doing this job outside of your regular workplace.

1- What is this mission called? 
(I have seen the word posting but it seems to be used for longer periods of time like one month or more.)

2- What word would you use for the extra money that you will be paid for doing that task?

Comment: Workplace SE might be of interest.

Comment: The term "remote assignment" covers everything but the precise duration of the task. You can clarify that by adding "one-day" before "remote assignment."

Answer (score 3):

The US military refers to this as **TDY** or **Temporary Duty**.

It is colloquially referred to as Temporary Duty Yonder, but the General Service Administration's [Acronym Dictionary](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/ext/public/site/FTR/file/Chapter301pAppD.html/category/21868/) defines it as Temporary Duty:

> TDY: Temporary Duty

The pay is referred to as **Temporary Duty Allowance** in the GSA's [Federal Travel Regulations](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/ext/public/site/FTR/file/Chapter301pAppD.html/category/21868/):

> Chapter 301—Temporary Duty (TDY) Travel Allowances

Answer (score 3):

In the States, extra payment for work outside your regular workplace is usually called 
[per diem](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/per+diem).

> per di•em
>   (pər ˈdi əm, ˈdaɪ əm) 
>   n.
>   2. a daily allowance, usu. for living expenses, as while traveling in connection with one's job.

Answer (score 3):

You are working **off-site** while you are in Manchester.

Merriam-Webster defines [off-site](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-site) as:

> away from the place of a business or activity

Answer (score 2):

1. work trip; [business trip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_trave)
2. travel [allowance](http://www.business.gov.au/business-topics/employing-people/work-and-travel/Pages/travel-allowances.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is the term *second* (pronounced as below), but it's pretty formal:

> **second**
>
> tr.v. seconded, seconding, seconds ...
>
> 3. (sĭ-kŏnd′) Chiefly British To transfer (a military officer, for example) temporarily.

[[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/second)]

Your second question may not have an answer other than *bonus* (or perhaps a coining such as *inconvenience bonus*).

Comment: To second is to transfer control of someone to another entity, for a period of time. i.e. If, instead of working for my normal employer, I was sent to work directly *for* another company in a capacity as though I was an employee of that company, I would have been seconded. A single day, working for my employer but working *at* a client's office, is not a secondment.

Comment: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second) does not require this stricter definition: **second** to move (someone) from a regular job to a different place, department, etc., for a short period of time >> It also broadens the sphere of application beyond the military.